# OC 3 Newletter products to maufacturer

Tags: newsletter, opencart-3

I hope someone can help me solve the problem. I have a newletter prepared for Oencart 3 and there is one area of it I am struggling with. I have to make it clear that I have no advanced experience in coding but muddle through with snippets. The area of the coding I am struggling with is here:

```
                  <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;padding:0 0 20px 0;" valign="top">
                  <span style="font-size:18px;line-height:1.2">
                     <p> We want you to be the first to know about latest products and specials in our store.</p><br>
                     **<p> We want you to be the first to know about the latest manufacturers machines in our store.</p><br>**
                    Check out this month's hot offers!
                  </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;">
                  {special_list}
            
                
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;padding:0 0 20px 0;" valign="top">
                  <span style="font-size:18px;line-height:1.2">
                    We are glad to present you our new products.
                  </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
                  <p style="text-align:left;font-size:12px;margin:0;text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #fff;">
```

Where the manufacturers are displayed I want to show every manufacturer's name and underneath their name, images and details of the products in stock. This is along the lines of 'for each manufacture show products'. What OC 3 code would do that? Would be grateful for any help.
MC

Comment: is anyone able to help with this?

Comment: It's not clear where this is being displayed, is it a module, is it in the footer, is it on a category page etc. Can you give more detail?

Comment: Thanks, just picked up your comment. Yes I should be clearer. The code I need is to be able to insert it into an email newsletter. The message area of the email is where the code is being entered . I need to call in each manufacturer and then the products that are connected to the manufacturer. I tried using for each etc. but that did not work.

Comment: Having no idea of where you're coding this, I would suggest you look into the controller method that loads this view. Are you familiar with Opencart's MVC framework?

Comment: You will see from the code originally posted. The coding is in the message area of the Mail on the OC admin Marketing. I am familiar with the MVC principal. The Manufacturers and products all exist in the databaseand I believe that it is these database items that can be drawn into an email using short codes. i.e. {{ manufacturer }} etc.

Comment: _It's definitely not clear from the code snippet where this HTML markup came from._ The built in email functionality uses a WYSIWYG editor and allows you to add your own email body. That unfortunately does not include a find & replace function for this sort of thing. There also isn't an ability to include code in the editor for security reasons. I don't see this working unless you have a placeholder [EXAMPLE] in the editor and some code to search for "[EXAMPLE]" and replace it with dynamic content.